# Bootstrap Navbar, changing background color only on one view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want my navbar to have a white background on all pages/views except on my home page. I want my navbar to be transparent background on the home page. Is there a way to achieve this in bootstrap?

I am on a rails app using bootstrap for the front end.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container yeh">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-top:3px;">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyAPP</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-container-right">

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse", id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li class="dropdown">
            <%= link_to 'Investments', proposals_path %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'Community', users_path %>
          </li>
          <% if current_user.present? %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'Dashboard', dashboard_path %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user) %>
          </li>
          <li>  
            <%= link_to 'Sign Out',destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
          </li>
          <% else %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'Register Now!', new_user_registration_path %>
          </li>
          <% end %>

        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by adding a custom class just for the homepage which sets the styling to transparent. For example, you could do something like:

On your homepage view add to the top:

```
<% provide(:nav_style, "transparent-nav") %>
```

In your header file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default <%= yield(:nav_style) %>">
```

In your scss file:

```
.navbar-default{
      background-color: white;
    &.transparent-nav {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the & css code do? Would I put that ruby code at the top of my home view?

Comment: @james the [& in Sass](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand) refers to the parent selector. So in this example, "&" would be the equivalent of `.navbar-default` so the outputted CSS would be `.navbar-default.transparent-nav`.

Comment: @james you would put the ruby code at the top of the home page view. It's used simply to pass the "transparent-nav" to the view file (in this case, the header file). As allejo mentioned, if you're not using Sass, you can simply write out the css. (Though I recommend checking out Sass when you get a chance :)